# Standard Min function does not give consistent answer with nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, min

I am not able to understand the behavior of `min` function . When `nan` is the first element, `min` says `nan` is the min element; when `nan` is not the first element, it gives the actual min value in the list.

Why am i getting different answer here?

```
>>> min([float('nan'),10,2,0])
nan

>>> min([10,float('nan'),2,0])
0
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because any real number compared with NaN is `False`, and because the implementation of `min` is logically equivalent to:

```
def min(seq):
    minimum, *rest = seq
    for i in rest:
        if i < minimum:
            minimum = i
    return minimum
```

If the first item of the list is NaN, then no other items in the list can be considered smaller than NaN because any `i < float('nan')` is `False`. On the other hand, if the first item is not NaN, then there is no chance NaN can be considered the smallest because any `float('nan') < i` is `False`.

If you would like `min` to disregard NaN you can use a key function to map it to infinity instead:

```
from math import isnan
print(min([float('nan'),10,2,0], key=lambda i: float('inf') if isnan(i) else i))
print(min([10,float('nan'),2,0], key=lambda i: float('inf') if isnan(i) else i))
```

This outputs:

```
0
0
```

Comment: Is there a way to instruct min function to not consider 'NaN' ?